# UI Router templateURl was not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my folder structure.
**theme**

**asset**

**src**

*app*

pages

- a.html
- b.html

  widgets

  app

**vendor**

**index.html**

When we use template URL for routing we got below issue

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/CAD1788/Desktop/Mobile/**srcapppagesa.html**. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

**app.js**:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      // For any unmatched url, send to /SearchResults
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/a1")

      $stateProvider
        .state('a1', {
            url: "/a1",
            templateUrl: "src\app\pages\a.html"
            //template:"<h1>one</h1>"
        })


        .state('b1', {
            url: "/b1",
            templateUrl: "src\app\pages\b.html" 
            //template:"<h1>Two</h1>"
        })

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li><a ui-sref="a1">Knowledge Base</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="b1">My Briefcase</a></li>
```

**Firefox Working Fine**

Comment: why are you using backslashes instead of forward slashes?  the error definitely shows that the backslashes have been stripped from the output, which is normal.

Comment: @Claies : We try forward slashes also but it samein chrome

Comment: I've never seen chrome strip out the correct slash from a URL path.

Comment: @Claies : we tried "templateUrl: "src/app/pages/a.html" it is working fine in firefox but chrome not working properly

Comment: and you got the same error message in chrome with that URL as the one you posted in the question body?  that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Have you tried in `localhost`?

Comment: @HarishKommuri : yes , We tried in my local

Comment: oh, also, chrome doesn't support ajax requests to the `file://` path;  if you are using ui-router, you **must** use a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this view block inside state:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/a1")

      $stateProvider
        .state('a1', {
            url: "/b1",
            views: {
              "main": {
                 templateUrl: "src/app/pages/b.html" 
             }
           }    
        })
});
```

And for routes to work, you should use some server for running application.

Comment: We got "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." error in console

Comment: Which server you are using for running the application.

Comment: I think you are running it as file, please use some server for running the app, then this issue will fix.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server, you can use this http-server.